# How to zoom in and out a part of the screen on mouse move in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, zooming

I have two `div`s on top of each other, each contains a canvas and some draggable/droppable images (I mean my display is not just a simple `div`).

I want to zoom in whenever mouse goes and zoom out when mouse leaves. I need something like this: http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo1

However, this one is applied to an image, mine is just a part of the screen (whatever you see from `div`s, `canvas`es, and other draggable/droppable objects on top of each other and now is under the mouse pointer and a small surrounding area).  How do I do this?